# Принцип работы wininet.InternetGetConnectedState()

Tags: сеть, windows-10, virtualbox, reverse-engineering

Я пытаюсь настроить виртуальную машину (*песочницу*) для тестирования одного проекта. Я использую VirtualBox и Windows10 для гостевой системы. Сеть настроена как *host only* (хост по умолчанию получает адрес 192.168.56.1, встроенный dhcp сервер VirtualBox - 192.168.56.100 и гость - 192.168.56.101)

Мне нужно чтобы программы, запущенные в гостевой системе, считали, что у них есть доступ в интернет. Для проверки они используют стандартный метод - [`InternetGetConnectedState()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384702(v=vs.85).aspx) из `wininet.dll`.

Сейчас `InternetGetConnectedState()` возвращает `FALSE` (и lpdwFlags=`0x10`).

Что мне надо поменять в конфигурации моей песочницы, чтобы `InternetGetConnectedState()` возвращала `TRUE`?
  Я могу запускать любые дополнительные сервисы на хосте или других виртуальных машинах - типа DNS или веб сервера. Я уже пробовала эмулировать [NCSI](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766017(v=ws.10).aspx) - но безрезультатно. Еще я пыталась анализировать весь траффик на виртуальном интерфейсе VirtualBox с помощью wireshark - но не смогла найти релевантные запросы.

Comment: если касаемой функции то на сайте microsoft написано: даже если функция вернула ложь - то параметры соединения она возвращает во второй параметр. значит нужно их проанализировать... https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/aa384702(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: В случае `FALSE` во флагах нет ничего интересного - все нули кроме флага наличия `RAS`, который установлен по умнолчанию.

Comment: а интернет то хоть есть на гостевой ОС? Через браузер ходит?

Comment: ответом на ваш вопрос будет: нужно чтобы интернет поступал в гостевую ОС через сетевую карту или модем. для проверки создайте соединение типа BRIDGE. Почитать про соединения можно тут: http://rus-linux.net/MyLDP/vm/VirtualBox-networking.html

Comment: Я надеялась, что я понятно объяснила, что интернета в гостевой системе нет. Если бы он был - не было бы и вопроса. Мой вопрос о том как в отсутствие интернета удовлетворить все проверки и заставить функцию возвращать нужный результат.

Comment: аа, вам просто обмануть программы надо. ну в голову приходит только одно это подменить эту функцию своей. вот первая ссылка которая попалась по этому поводу: https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/140456/